# Xamarin Forms - retrieve value of dynamically added entry control value on button click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to get all `entry` controls value on `button` click.

My code is as below - this is how I am adding dynamic control on page:

```
        public BookSeat()
        {
            ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView();
            StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["NoPersonEntry"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                stack.Children.Add(
                    new StackLayout()
                    {
                        Children = {
                            new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text = "First Name: ", WidthRequest = 100,StyleId="FnameLabel"+i },
                            new Entry() {StyleId="FnameEntry"+i }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Save"
            };

            button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
            stack.Children.Add(button);

            scroll.Content = stack;
            this.Content = scroll;
        }
```

And below code is for I want to get value on `button` click

```
        public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Here I want to get value
        }
```

Comment: You should use `MVVM` and Data binding to get values, this is wrong way. You should use `ListView` and not StackLayout with multiple entries in it, you should create `ItemTemplate` with `Entry` and bind `Text` property to some model.

Comment: @AkashKava Thanks for reply, can you please give some example or sample data?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/ListView/SwitchEntryTwoBinding/

Comment: sorry @AkashKava, but sample code link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to store your entries in a list so that you can access them later on.

For example :

```
private List<Entry> _myentries = new List<Entry>();

public BookSeat()
        {
            ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView();
            StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(Application.Current.Properties["NoPersonEntry"]);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
var entry = new Entry() {StyleId="FnameEntry"+i };
_myentries.Add(entry);
                stack.Children.Add(
                    new StackLayout()
                    {
                        Children = {
                            new Label (){TextColor = Color.Blue, Text = "First Name: ", WidthRequest = 100,StyleId="FnameLabel"+i },
                            entry 
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
[...]
        }
```

Now you can do this :

```
public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           foreach(var entry in _myentries)
           {
              var text = entry.Text;//here we go
           }


 }
```